# Extract a dictionnary value in Python

Tags: python

I have an API call result in Python which is returning the following:

```
b'[{"type":"deposit","currency":"bch","amount":"0.00000001","available":"0.00000001"}]'
```

I tried to extract the value `0.00000001` but without any success.
I know how to extract values from lists and dictionaries in Python,but as there is the `b'` value before the results I am not figuring out how to get it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing HTTP Response in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049767/parsing-http-response-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert dictionary to bytes and back again python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232011/convert-dictionary-to-bytes-and-back-again-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you have here is actually a bytes string, rather than a Python dictionary. Try this to convert it to a dictionary (actually a list containing a dictionary given the square brackets):

```
import json
data = json.loads(b'[{"type":"deposit","currency":"bch","amount":"0.00000001","available":"0.00000001"}]')
value = data[0]['amount']
```

Comment: it works under python2 but I am using python3, current error when executing your lines is TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

Comment: I just tested on Python 3 and it works correctly for me. To be exact, Python 3.6.1, and json module version 2.0.9.

Comment: Problem solved, that was it, under 3.5 it was not working, updated to 3.6.1 and problem got solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The API is probably returning json data, you should parse it this way:

```
import json
data = json.loads(json_data)
print data[0]['amount']
```

json_data is what the API returns