# Python: Convert dictionary to bytes

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to convert a dictionary to bytes but facing issues in converting it to a correct format.

First, I'm trying to map an dictionary with an custom schema. Schema is defined as follows -

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, name=None, code=None):
        self.name = name
        self.code = code

class UserSchema:
    name = fields.Str()
    code = fields.Str()

@post_load
 def create_userself, data):
    return User(**data)
```

My Dictionary structure is as follows-

```
user_dict = {'name': 'dinesh', 'code': 'dr-01'}
```

I'm trying to map the dictionary to User schema with the below code

```
schema = UserSchema(partial=True)
user = schema.loads(user_dict).data
```

While doing, **schema.loads** expects the input to be str, bytes or bytearray. Below are the steps that I followed to convert dictionary to Bytes

```
import json
user_encode_data = json.dumps(user_dict).encode('utf-8')
print(user_encode_data)
```

**Output:**

```
b'{"name ": "dinesh", "code ": "dr-01"}
```

If I try to map with the schema I'm not getting the required schema object. But, if I have the output in the format given below I can able to get the correct schema object.

```
b'{\n  "name": "dinesh",\n  "code": "dr-01"}\n'
```

Any suggestions how can I convert a dictionary to Bytes?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use `indent` option in `json.dumps()` to obtain `\n` symbols:

```
import json

user_dict = {'name': 'dinesh', 'code': 'dr-01'}
user_encode_data = json.dumps(user_dict, indent=2).encode('utf-8')
print(user_encode_data)
```

Output:

```
b'{\n  "name": "dinesh",\n  "code": "dr-01"\n}'
```

Comment: We do not need `indent=2`, so `json.dumps(user_dict).encode('utf-8')` will be enough

Comment: Prettiest way: `json.dumps(user_dict, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')).encode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 8):

You can use Base64 library to convert string dictionary to bytes, and although you can convert bytes result to a dictionary using json library. Try this below sample code.

```
import base64
import json


input_dict = {'var1' : 0, 'var2' : 'some string', 'var1' : ['listitem1','listitem2',5]}

message = str(input_dict)
ascii_message = message.encode('ascii')
output_byte = base64.b64encode(ascii_message)

msg_bytes = base64.b64decode(output_byte)
ascii_msg = msg_bytes.decode('ascii')
# Json library convert stirng dictionary to real dictionary type.
# Double quotes is standard format for json
ascii_msg = ascii_msg.replace("'", "\"")
output_dict = json.loads(ascii_msg) # convert string dictionary to dict format

# Show the input and output
print("input_dict:", input_dict, type(input_dict))
print()
print("base64:", output_byte, type(output_byte))
print()
print("output_dict:", output_dict, type(output_dict))
```

Output:

```
>>> print("input_dict:", input_dict, type(input_dict))
input_dict: {'var1': ['listitem1', 'listitem2', 5], 'var2': 'some string'} <class 'dict'>
>>> print()

>>> print("base64:", output_byte, type(output_byte))
base64: b'eyd2YXIxJzogWydsaXN0aXRlbTEnLCAnbGlzdGl0ZW0yJywgNV0sICd2YXIyJzogJ3NvbWUgc3RyaW5nJ30=' <class 'bytes'>
>>> print()

>>> print("output_dict:", output_dict, type(output_dict))
output_dict: {'var1': ['listitem1', 'listitem2', 5], 'var2': 'some string'} <class 'dict'>
```