# how to make my bot in discord.py loop through the list and display the elements one by one

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have a function that gets the top 10 cryptocurrencies by market cap

```py
import os 
import json
from requests import Session
def get_top10():
    CMC_API_KEY=os.environ.get('CMC')
    parameters={
                
                'start':1,
                'limit':5000
                }
    headers={
                'Accepts':'application/json',
                'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY':CMC_API_KEY
                }
    session=Session()
    session.headers.update(headers)
        
    url='https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/map'
    response=session.get(url,params=parameters)
    json_file=json.loads(response.text)['data']
    top10_rank_to_slug = {d['rank']: d['slug'] for d in json_file}
    top_10 = sorted(top10_rank_to_slug.items())[:10]
    for rank,name in top_10:
        print(rank,name)
```

but in order to pass it to my discord bot the function has to return a value not print it how can I do that (I want the bot to loop through the list then return the items one by one I dont want the bot to just return the list )

```py
@client.command()
@commands.check(check_channel)
async def top10(ctx):
    await ctx.send(get_top10())
client.run(token)
```

how do you suggest I do that??

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind for me is to return the dictionary, *then* loop through the dictionary when sending the messages.

```
import os 
import json
from requests import Session
def get_top10():
    CMC_API_KEY=os.environ.get('CMC')
    parameters={'start':1,
                'limit':5000
               }
    headers={'Accepts':'application/json',
             'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY':CMC_API_KEY
            }
    session=Session()
    session.headers.update(headers)
    
    url='https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/map'
    response=session.get(url,params=parameters)
    json_file=json.loads(response.text)['data']
    top10_rank_to_slug = {d['rank']: d['slug'] for d in json_file}
    top_10 = sorted(top10_rank_to_slug.items())[:10]
    return top_10
```

Then you can `await ctx.send` the dictionary by each `key:value` pair:

```
@client.command()
@commands.check(check_channel)
async def top10(ctx):
top_10 = get_top_10()
for key in top_10:
    await ctx.send(f"{key} is the key and {top_10[key]} is the value.")
           
client.run(token)
```

There are MANY other solutions and ways to do this, but this is frankly the least intrusive to your code and one of the easier to understand ones.

> I want the bot to loop through the list then return the items one by one I dont want the bot to just return the list

I do not necessarily know why you want the above specifically, but if you share that, I may be able to help in a more suitable manner. Another simple solution is to turn the dictionary into a string in the function, then return the string already preformatted for the bot to send.

Comment: thank you it worked , but the bot is displaying the result one by one is there any way to store the file then display it directly like not sending 10 messages I want the bot to send one message that contains everything

Comment: I would recommend taking a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547274/convert-a-python-dict-to-a-string-and-back) at this post. The other option is simply converting the dictionary it produces directly into a string, with each new `key : value` pair making a new line. Replace every comma with a `\n`.